# count the number of each prime factor of a number

Tags: java, prime-factoring

I want to count the number of each prime factor of an integer then print the highest number of counts. e.g. 720 = 2^4 * 3^2 * 5^1. so I want to print Maximum Number of Time occurrence = 4 and the number is 2. I try to use `Integer.max()`, but that didn't work.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        num = in.nextInt();
        TreeMap<Integer, Integer> factors = new TreeMap<>();

        for (int i =2; i < num; i++){
            int count = 0;
            while (num%i == 0){
                System.out.println(i + " ");
                num = num/i;
                count ++;
            }
            if (count > 0){
                factors.put(i, count);
            }
        }
        if (num > 2){
            System.out.println(num + " ");
            factors.put(num, 1);
        }

        System.out.println( "-------------" );
        for( Integer factor : factors.keySet() ){
            System.out.println( factor + "^" + factors.get( factor ) );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the prime which occurs most then you can just check after each prime has been tested.  For this, a map is not really necessary.  Note that multiple primes may occur the same number of times.  If there is a tie, this only saves the first one encountered.

```
int num;
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
num = in.nextInt();
int primeFactor = 0;
int count = 0;
int maxCount = 0;
int inc = 1; // initial increment.
int i = 2;   // intitial prime
while (num > 1) {
    count = 0;
    while (num%i == 0) {
        num = num/i;
        count++;
    }

    // here check current count against maxCount and
    // alter if required.
    if (count > maxCount) {
       maxCount = count;
       primeFactor = i;
    }
    if (count > 0) {
        System.out.printf("Prime = %d, count = %d%n", i, count);
    }
    i+=inc;  // bump by 1 to get 3 and then
    inc = 2; // start incrementing by 2
}

// and print the results.
System.out.println("First highest occuring prime = " + primeFactor);
System.out.println("MaxCount = " + maxCount);
```